# Using array to create new array

Tags: jquery, arrays, object

http://jsfiddle.net/Ug4F4/1/

```
   var indexes = {
            'spear' : $('#commands_table th:has(img[src*="unit_spear"])').index(),
            'sword' : $('#commands_table th:has(img[src*="unit_sword"])').index(),
            'axe' : $('#commands_table th:has(img[src*="unit_axe"])').index(),
            'archer' : $('#commands_table th:has(img[src*="unit_archer"])').index(),
            'spy' : $('#commands_table th:has(img[src*="unit_spy"])').index(),
            'light' : $('#commands_table th:has(img[src*="unit_light"])').index(),
            'marcher' : $('#commands_table th:has(img[src*="unit_marcher"])').index(),
            'heavy' : $('#commands_table th:has(img[src*="unit_heavy"])').index(),
            'ram' : $('#commands_table th:has(img[src*="unit_ram"])').index(),
            'cata' : $('#commands_table th:has(img[src*="unit_catapult"])').index(),
            'snob' : $('#commands_table th:has(img[src*="unit_snob"])').index(),
            'knight' : $('#commands_table th:has(img[src*="unit_knight"])').index(),

            };


     for (var key in indexes) {
     if (indexes[key] < 0)
    delete(indexes[key]);
    }
```

json stringify alert:

```
   {"spear":3,"sword":4,"axe":5,"spy":6,"light":7,"heavy":8,"ram":9,"cata":10,"snob":11}
```

I now have all the indexes I need to find every matching value for each unit (by index).

```
    var matchingvalues = ['spear', 'sword', 'axe', 'archer',
         'spy', 'light', 'marcher', 'heavy',
         'ram', 'cata', 'noble', 'knight'],


 var matchingvalues = bevelnaam.closest('tr').find('td').eq(indexes).text();
```

What it needs to become:

```
    var matchingvalues = ['spear' : numberofspear
   'sword' : numberofsword' ]
```

etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated (and some explanation with it even more :))

Edit: added fiddle. You can see every tr looks the same. I'm trying to find all the numbers on the right for every tr and putting them in an array (I'm going to do something with those values but thats not really relevant). You can see those images at the top of the column, those images are the units (spear, sword, etc) and I need the value for every unit for every tr (in my each tr function) in an array of some sort.

Comment: This makes absolutely no sense? You need an object with the keys you have and the number of ..... what exactly? The index is where the element is in the DOM in regards to the parent element etc. is that what you want in the object ? Try explaining what you're trying to do like you would to a five year old kid, or make a fiddle where you can show us exactly what keys and values you'd like, and where they are coming from ?

Comment: Some HTML would be nice, and 'bevelnaam'. is it something like this? `var matchingvalues = [{'spear' : numberofspear},
   {'sword' : numberofsword}];`. access like so: `matchingvalues[int].spear` ? "[]" creates an array not an object

Comment: Updated my question and added fiddle

Comment: I really don't get it, but I created a quick fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/Ug4F4/2/, click on the first links in the list, under "Bevel", and you'll get the values of that row in the console, should be a start at least ?

Comment: I already know how to get them, at least one by one. It's just that I want to use my array of indexes automatically (so in one function) to find all the matching values for each unit type and put those in another index :)

Comment: I mean array; not index. lol :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to accomplish what this, you will need to loop over `matchingvalues` and perform a function then store the results in a new object.

Since you are already using jQuery, you may want to look at [jQuery .map()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) or simply use forEach [MDN - forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

You could do something like this:

```js
var mapped_matching_values = {};

matchingvalues.forEach(function(elem, index){
    //extract the key name (i.e. spear, sword, etc)
    var key_name = matchingvalues[index];

    //extract the text 
    var text = bevelnaam.closest('tr').find('td').eq(indexes).text();

    //insert into object with processed values
    mapped_matching_values[key_name] = text;
});

//now use mapped_matching_values
```

Comment: My indexes are in an array though, can I just use it like that? (Indexes are the first array in my fiddle/question).